# How can I see what URL Gradle got a dependency from?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I'd like to see from which URL Gradle got a certain dependency.

Gradle does list the URLs it looked at when it fails to find a dependency ("Searched in the following locations: ..."), but I'd like to see this for a dependency that isn't missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gradle --debug` will give you all the details. Note that if an artifact was fetched previously, gradle will only show that it was resolved from the cache instead of the original URL.